# How to extract a single letter or number from a string?

Tags: php, explode

I need to extract a specific letter or number from string.

```
<div id="craftysyntax_1" style="float: right;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://livehelp.clipboards.com/livehelp_js.php?eo=0&amp;department=1&amp;serversession=1&amp;pingtimes=10&amp;dynamic=Y&amp;creditline=W"></script></div>
```

From this **div** with `id="craftysyntax_1"` I want to extract just the number **1** from this **craftysyntax_1**, i am trying with explode but it does not work for me or maybe I am doing something wrong.

Here is what I have tried :

```
$myString = '<div id="craftysyntax_1" style="float: right;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://livehelp.clipboards.com/livehelp_js.php?eo=0&amp;department=1&amp;serversession=1&amp;pingtimes=10&amp;dynamic=Y&amp;creditline=W"></script></div>';
            $strArray = explode('craftysyntax_', $myString, 1);
            print_r($myString);
```

How can I achieve what I want?

Comment: a `regEx` would seem like the ideal solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `regEx` to accomplish your goal as in this example

```
$myString = '<div id="craftysyntax_123" style="float: right;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://livehelp.clipboards.com/livehelp_js.php?eo=0&amp;department=1&amp;serversession=1&amp;pingtimes=10&amp;dynamic=Y&amp;creditline=W"></script></div>';
$pttn = '@craftysyntax_(\d{1,})@';
preg_match( $pttn, $myString, $matches );

echo '<pre>',print_r($matches,1),'</pre>';
```

This will output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => craftysyntax_123
    [1] => 123
)
```

so you can explicitly target the integer using `$matches[1]`

Answer (score 1):

```
preg_match("/craftysyntax_(.*)\\" /", $myString, $output_array);
echo $output_array[1];
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

> I want to extract just the number 1 from this ***craftysyntax_1***

Use `preg_match` function:

```
$myString = '<div id="craftysyntax_1" style="float: right;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://livehelp.clipboards.com/livehelp_js.php?eo=0&amp;department=1&amp;serversession=1&amp;pingtimes=10&amp;dynamic=Y&amp;creditline=W"></script></div>';

preg_match("/id=[\"']craftysyntax_(\d+)[\"']/", $myString, $matches);
$craft_number = $matches[1];

print_r($craft_number);  // 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this by using preg_match:

```
$myString = '<div id="craftysyntax_1" style="float: right;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://livehelp.clipboards.com/livehelp_js.php?eo=0&amp;department=1&amp;serversession=1&amp;pingtimes=10&amp;dynamic=Y&amp;creditline=W"></script></div>';
preg_match("/id=[\"']craftysyntax_(\d+)[\"']/", $myString, $output);
print_r($output);  //Array ( [0] => id="craftysyntax_1" [1] => 1 )
print_r($output[1]);//1
```

Answer (score 0):

You really [shouldn't use regex to try and parse HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590747/using-regular-expressions-to-parse-html-why-not).

An alternative solution, use `DOMDocument` to extract the ID you want:

```
$str = '<div id="craftysyntax_1" style="float: right;"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://livehelp.clipboards.com/livehelp_js.php?eo=0&amp;department=1&amp;serversession=1&amp;pingtimes=10&amp;dynamic=Y&amp;creditline=W"></script></div>';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$src = $dom->getElementsByTagName('div')->item(0);
$attr = $src->attributes->getNamedItem('id')->value;
```

This will give you the value `craftysyntax_1`. Now you can easily grab everything after the *last* underscore, if it exists:

```
if (($pos = strrpos($attr, '_')) !== false) {
    echo substr($attr, $pos + 1);
}
```